# JCR SQL2 like query with escape not working

Tags: jcr-sql2

This query runs fine:

```
    SELECT n.* FROM [nt:unstructured] AS n
    WHERE n.property LIKE 'value'
```

But this query does not:

```
    SELECT n.* FROM [nt:unstructured] AS n
    WHERE n.property LIKE 'value' ESCAPE '#'
```

The error isn't helpful either:

```
    Query: SELECT n.* FROM [nt:unstructured] AS n WHERE n.property LIKE 'value' ESCAPE(*)'#'; expected: <end>
```

So what gives?